# Cannot find php file

Tags: php, html

I have an HTMLfile that posts form data to a PHP file (or it is supposed to anyway). The HTML and PHP files are in the same folder in my project, but when I go to submit the form, I get a notification that "the resource cannot be found. The name of my PHP file is "patient_json.php".

Here is my html

```
@using OnboardingProject.App_Code
@using OnboardingProject.Controllers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Patients";
}

<div class="title">
    <div>
        <h1 style="float: left">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rmm" style="float: right; display: inline-block">
        <ul>
            <li><button id="NewPatient">New Patient</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_content">
    <div id="modal_window" title="Complete the form below to add a new patient:">
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a id="modal_close" href="#">close <b>X</b></a></div>

        <form id="add_patient" method="POST" action="patient_json.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <p><label>First Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="fname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Last Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="lname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="bday" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Site Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="location" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>SSN<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="pat_ssn" value=""></label></p>
        <p><input type="submit" id="addPatient" value="Add Patient"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="patient_table">
        <table id="patients">
            <tr>
                <th id="p_name">Patient Name</th>
                <th id="p_site">Site</th>
                <th id="dob">Date of Birth</th>
                <th id="ssn">SSN</th>
                <th id="edits"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PatientInfo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

// check if all form data are submited, else output error message
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['bday']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['pat_ssn'])) {
  // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
  if(empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['bday']) || empty($_POST['location']) || empty($_POST['pat_ssn'])) {
    echo 'All fields are required';
  }
  else {
    // adds form data into an array
    $formdata = array(
      'firstname'=> $_POST['fname'],
      'lastname'=> $_POST['lname'],
      'bday'=> $_POST['bday'],
      'location'=> $_POST['location'],
      'ssn'=> $_POST['pat_ssn']
    );

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($formdata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "pat_data.txt"
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('pat_data.txt', $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Unable to save data in "formdata.txt"';
  }
}
else echo 'Form fields not submitted';

// path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'pat_data.txt';

// check if the file exists
if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
  // gets json-data from file
  $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

  // converts json string into array
  $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

  // Now you can use the array $arr_data with json-data saved in text file
  var_export($arr_data);        // Test to see the array
}
else echo 'The file '. $filetxt .' not exists';

// path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'pat_data.txt';

// check if all form data are submited, else output error message
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['bday']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['pat_ssn'])) {
  // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
  if(empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['bday']) || empty($_POST['location']) || empty($_POST['pat_ssn'])) {
    echo 'All fields are required';
  }
  else {
    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $formdata = array(
      'firstname'=> $_POST['fname'],
      'lastname'=> $_POST['lname'],
      'bday'=> $_POST['bday'],
      'location'=> $_POST['location'],
      'ssn'=> $_POST['pat_ssn']
    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'pat_data.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $formdata;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "pat_data.txt"
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('pat_data.txt', $jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Unable to save data in "pat_data.txt"';
  }
}
else echo 'Form fields not submited';

?>
```

Again, they are in the same folder in the project so I can't figure out why the PHP file cannot be found. Any ideas?

Comment: unless its a typpo, your form is submitting to "patient_json.php", which is not what you want, as per your notes.

Comment: sorry that is a type-o. the php file name is patient_json.php. Sorry about that everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting to `patient_json.php` in your HTML code, not `patient_data.php`.

Comment: sorry that is a type-o. the php file name is patient_json.php. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP script is failing because it never enters the main if (the $_POST vars are not set). Fields in POST forms are referred to by name, not id.

Simply add name="fname" as an additional parameter, right next to id="fname", and so on for each input field.

```
<input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="fname" value="">
```

becomes

```
<input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="fname" name="fname" value="">
```

Comment: added the name parameters. still getting "resource cannot be found" for the php file

Comment: Confirm that the file name in your script, the action="filename.php", is the correct name of your php file. Also confirm that the URL in your browser after you click submit on the form has the correct name of the PHP file. Lastly, confirm that your PHP file is uploaded to the server in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0):

You said the name of your php file is patient_data.php but your code has:

```
<form id="add_patient" method="POST" action="patient_json.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

The action is the page your form will take you to so it should be:

```
<form id="add_patient" method="POST" action="patient_data.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: sorry that is a type-o. the php file name is patient_json.php. Sorry about that

Comment: The script still doesn't work. That was just a type-o when I typed up the question.

Answer (score 0):

you form action is submitting to "form_json.php" but you said your file name is "form_data.php", change your action to that name

Comment: The form action is 'patient_json.php', not 'form_json.php'.

Comment: sorry that is a type-o. the php file name is patient_json.php. Sorry about that